# Get events that have an custom property set by an add-in

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

This question is a follow-up to [Get custom property set in Outlook Add-In via Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130810/get-custom-property-set-in-outlook-add-in-via-microsoft-graph).

My Outlook Office.js add-in is adding some custom properties to an event. It works as expected and I can access those properties using Microsoft Graph, with following `GET` request:

```
/v1.0/me/events/{event-id}?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20cecp-b7ff386a-234a-4a38-84bc-e5ae4684b7af')
```

But now I try to subscribe to push notifications by posting such body to the push notifications endpoint (`/v1.0/subscriptions`):

```
  {
    changeType: "created,updated,deleted",
    notificationUrl: `[...my url...]`,
    resource: `/users/${userData.id}/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep%3A%20ep%2Fid%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20cecp-b7ff386a-234a-4a38-84bc-e5ae4684b7af')`,
    expirationDateTime: tomorrow,
    clientState: "SecretClientState"
  }
```

But I'm getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: Bad Request]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "01dcece6-0103-4bef-8231-e9ab9480402a",
      "date": "2017-04-04T20:20:58"
    }
  }
}
```

Tried to set the resource in the request unescaped, but with same result, next thing I tried is the `$filter` functionality, so did a get request in following format using the MS Graph explorer:

```
/v1.0/me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep%3A%20ep%2Fid%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20cecp-b7ff386a-234a-4a38-84bc-e5ae4684b7af')
```

but got following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
        "message": "The filter expression for $filter does not match to a single extended property and a value restriction.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "aca7c8ed-6e30-4490-8feb-7f1d2aed6b88",
            "date": "2017-04-04T20:38:28"
        }
    }
}
```

does it mean that I also have to filter by value and not only `id`?

That would be an issue because I want the events that have the property set, but I don't know the value beforehand, I want to read it after I get a push notification.

Is there a way to get events which simply have a custom property set by my add-in, and subscribe to push notifications for events which has this custom property?

**EDIT:**

When I change `id` to `PropertyId` as suggested in the answer I'm getting:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'PropertyId' on type 'microsoft.graph.singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1d3db71e-6ee2-4680-9317-64687813c52a",
            "date": "2017-04-05T13:49:45"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT-2:**

Now when I add filtering by `value`, it works:

```
/v1.0/me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-b7ff386a-234a-4a38-84bc-e5ae4684b7af' and ep/value eq 'foo')
```

but I wan't all the events with that property regardless the value of it...

**EDIT-3**

No trying by filtering by `value` but using the non-equal `ne` operator:

```
/v1.0/me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-b7ff386a-234a-4a38-84bc-e5ae4684b7af' and ep/value ne 'Foo')
```

it *seems* to work, but this time it looks like it just ignores the filter and returns all events, with and without that custom property set from the add-in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several tries I found a way to filter for events/messages that have a custom property regardless it's value:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-b7ff386a-234a-4a38-84bc-e5ae4684b7af' and ep/value ne null)
```

with the added important part being `and ep/value ne null`, whereas something like `and ep/value ne 'fooo'` didn't work, it just returned everything.

Above filtering works also for filtering of events for which we want subscribe to push events.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the filter query should be

PropertyId eq ....

instead of Id eq ...

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue, after making that change I'm getting a different error - updated my answer with the response I'm getting.