# Outlook Rest API push notifications: Filter the notifications based on specific custom property set by outlook add-in

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I followed same steps that are mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217399/ms-graph-outlook-rest-api-get-events-that-have-an-custom-property-set-by-an-web), to filter the push notification events based on custom properties set by outlook add-in.

Below is the resource link that I used while subscribing to push notifications.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/?$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties%2FAny(ep%3A%20ep%2FPropertyId%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20cecp-7e248e5e-204e-4e2b-aa0f-788af20fc21c'%20and%20ep%2FValue%20ne%20null)
```

It's filtering the calendar items that are having custom properties set by add-in, irrespective of whatever custom property it is.
By looking at this resource link, we could say that no where we have mentioned the custom property name. But my add-in sets more than one custom properties to calendar item. I want to filter all calendar items that are having specific custom property. For example, My add-in sets any one of the below custom property to calendar based on business login.

Custom property 1:

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync((result) => {
     const props = result.value;
     props.set("my_prop_one", "test_value_one");
     props.saveAsync((saveResult) => console.log("Successfull"));
 });
```

Custom property 2:

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
 item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync((result) => {
      const props = result.value;
      props.set("my_prop_two", "test_value_tw");
      props.saveAsync((saveResult) => console.log("Successful"));
 });
```

Now I want to filter all calendar items that are having custom property `my_prop_one`.

**EDIT 1:**

As suggested by @Jason Johnston in one of the comments, I cross verified the property name and it's GUID using MFCMapi. Both property name and it's GUID values are correct.

MFCMapi data of custom property `meetingsetby`.
[image]

Then I collected data from MFCMapi and prepared the below url to filter calendar items that are having custom property `meetingsetby` and it's value `webex`.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Events?$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties%2FAny(ep%3A%20ep%2FPropertyId%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20meetingsetby'%20and%20ep%2FValue%20eq%20'webex')
```

And below is the response from `postman` when I make the get call using above url.
[image]

As you can see, response has empty list even though there is one calendar item with custom property `meetingsetby` and value `webex`.

Then I set the `SingleValueExtendedProperty` to calendar item using outlook Rest API as described in [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations#CreateExtendedPropertyInExistingItem). Below is the sample request data,
[image: Outlook Rest API request to set Single Value Extended Property]

MFCMapi data of `SingleValueExtendedProperty`
[image: MFCMapi data of SingleValueExtendedProperty]

Then I collected data from MFCMapi and prepared the below url to filter calendar items that are having `singleValueExtendedProperty` set in above step.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Events?$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties%2FAny(ep%3A%20ep%2FPropertyId%20eq%20'String%20{6666AA44-4659-4830-9070-00047EC6AC6E}%20Name%20RestApiSingleValueExtendedProperty'%20and%20ep%2FValue%20eq%20'Set this property using REST API')
```

And below is the response from `postman` when I make the get call using above url.
[image: Filter response based on singleValueExtendedProperty]

As you can see, I can successfully filter the calendar items using `singleValueExtendedProperty`. But my requirement is filter calendar items that are having specific custom property set by my outlook web add-in.

Any suggestion/answers would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom properties set by an add-in (using the [CustomProperties](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/CustomProperties) interface) are **not** equivalent to normal MAPI named properties. Essentially what the add-in APIs do is take all of your "custom properties", serialize them as a JSON payload, then save it in a single MAPI named property, which will have the name `cecp-{some guid}`, and the property set GUID `PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`. The `{some-guid}` part of the name is equal to the `Id` of your add-in. This is all specified in [MS-OXCEXT section 2.2.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968549(v=exchg.80).aspx).

So the end result here is that you cannot use `$filter` on the values you set in the `CustomProperties` interface, because there is no `SingleValueExtendedProperty` with that name and value. Instead, there is a single `SingleValueExtendedProperty` with the name `cecp-{some guid}`, with a string value that's the JSON serialization of ALL the custom props you set via the `CustomProperties` interface.

So how can you do what you want? Well, going back to your original URL, you can get all messages that have ANY properties set by your add-in by doing

```
$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties/Any
  (ep: ep/PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
  Name cecp-7e248e5e-204e-4e2b-aa0f-788af20fc21c' and ep/Value ne null)
```

Replacing the GUID after the `cecp-` with the GUID ID for your add-in.

But of course you want to find just the ones that have a specific property (`meetingsetby`) set to a specific value (`webex`). Unfortunately our API won't support substring searches when filtering the `SingleValueExtendedProperties`. So what you'd need to do is get all messages with any properties set by your add-in, then do your own filtering logic to find just the ones you want. So basically you would load them in memory, then check the value of that property yourself to find the ones you want.

You can make sure that the value of the property is included in the response by using an `$expand` clause. Something like this:

```
?$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties/Any
  (ep: ep/PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
  Name cecp-7e248e5e-204e-4e2b-aa0f-788af20fc21c' and ep/Value ne null)
  &$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String
  {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-7e248e5e-204e-4e2b-aa0f-788af20fc21c')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the above filter. After that I am not receiving the push notification at all. Below is the new filter `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Events?$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties%2FAny(ep%3A%20ep%2FPropertyId%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20my_prop_one'%20and%20ep%2FValue%20ne%20null)`. When I make get request to above url, I am receiving empty array, even though there are multiple calendar items that are having `my_prop_one` custom property.

Comment: The GUID may be the wrong one. I'm at Ignite this week and can't run a test, but you should be able to find the property with MFCMapi and determine the GUID.

Comment: I cross verified the property name and it's GUID using MFCMapi. Both property name and it's GUID values are correct.

Comment: @Johnston I updated the question with my observations.

Comment: Ok. I forgot that add-in custom properties aren't just regular custom properties, so I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @Johnston Thanks for your answer. I can't load them in memory and apply filter. As I want to subscribe for the rest push notifications when user updates/deletes the calendar item that has specific custom property set by web add-in.

Comment: Best you can do is filter on the overall property set changing (filter on the cecp- property).