# Microsoft Graph $filter by singleValueExtendedProperties and get this extended properties too

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm exporting app specific events to MS Calendar.
To distinguish them from others (for later updating/removing by the app) I set an extended property for them (with `SingleValueExtendedProperties`).

I found out how to filter events by the presence (and value) of this extended property
([Get events that have an custom property set by an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217399/get-events-that-have-an-custom-property-set-by-an-add-in) e.g.)

I also found out how to ask for the value of this property by `$expand`-ing particular event id -
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get

What I can't find is how to get a **list** of matched events **and** this extended property for every item. For all the examples I checked (under the second link there're many) it is stated that `The response does not include the matching extended property.` Why so and how then? Obviously, it would be not very performant to get `$filter`-ed list and then `$expand` every item with the separate requests...

I would be very appreciated for any help/hints/thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It could be done with "open extension":

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_post_opentypeextension

The workflow is following:

1. fill `extensions` field when creating/updating event:

   ```
   subject: 'my event',
   ... 
   extensions: [{
     '@odata.type': 'Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension',
     extensionName: MS_EXTENSION_ID,
     appSpecificId: myId
   }]
   ```
2. then use a query like this to filter **and** expand "open extension" values:

   ```
   url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events'
     + '?$select=subject,start,end'
     + '&$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq \'' + MS_EXTENSION_ID + '\')'
     + '&$expand=Extensions($filter=id eq \'' + MS_EXTENSION_ID + '\')',
   ```

`MS_EXTENSION_ID` could be just a reverse domain name, like `Biz.MyCompany.Events`

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to list the event and extend the property of every item.

We can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get). This document say that,

`Using the query parameter $expand allows you to get the specified resource instance expanded with a specific extended property. 
Use a $filter and eq operator on the id property to specify the extended property.
This is currently the only way to get the singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty object that represents an extended property.`

We can submit this feature request on [the User Voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/)