# Not receiving Change Notification of Calendar Events containing custom properties

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, change-notification

We want to receive change notifications from our user's Outlook calendars.  We'd like to limit those notifications to only those calendar items that contain our custom property.

**CODE WHICH CREATES CALENDAR EVENT**

```
private static async Task<Event> CreateAppointmentAsync(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{

    var newEvent = new Microsoft.Graph.Event
    {
        Subject = "Test Calendar Appointmnt",
        Start = new DateTimeTimeZone() { TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, DateTime = "2020-11-21T21:00:00" },
        End = new DateTimeTimeZone() { TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, DateTime = "2020-11-21T22:00:00" },
        Location = new Location() { DisplayName = "Somewhere" },
        Body = new ItemBody { Content = "Some Random Text" },

    };

    Microsoft.Graph.Event addedEvent;
    try
    {
        newEvent.SingleValueExtendedProperties = new EventSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage();
        newEvent.SingleValueExtendedProperties.Add(new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty { Id = "String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name CompanyID", Value = "12345" });


        addedEvent = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events.Request().AddAsync(newEvent);

   

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }


    return addedEvent;

  

}
```

**THE SUBSCRIPTION CODE SNIPPET**

```
var subscription = new Subscription
{
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl ="<OUR-URL>",                                   
    Resource = "me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name CompanyID' and ep/value ne null)",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-11-13T18:23:45.9356913Z"),
    ClientState = "custom_data_state",
    LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2"
};
```

The subscription is created successfully, but notifications are not being sent for those items containing the specific custom property described above.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, according to this post [Get events that have an custom property set by an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217399/get-events-that-have-an-custom-property-set-by-an-add-in), the ability to filter notifications based on custom events is possible.   Is it not possible for calendar events?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was only capturing the "created" notification.   I neglected to add "updated" and "deleted".

I was testing with an event that already existed in my calendar. No events were being fired because I didn't create the subscription to detect updates and deletes.

Here is the corrected subscription:

```
var subscription = new Subscription
{
    ChangeType = "created,updated,deleted",
    NotificationUrl ="<OUR-URL>",                                   
    Resource = "me/events/?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name CompanyID' and ep/value ne null)",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-11-13T18:23:45.9356913Z"),
    ClientState = "custom_data_state",
    LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2"
};
```