# How can i know that a meeting is already created or not?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way i can find out if the current meeting window from which i opened the add-in (compose mode) is from a new meeting or from an already created meeting that i opened for edit?

Comment: There isn't an API that reveals this information currently. What is your scenario for needing to know the difference?

Comment: I need to take ahold of the itemId so i can call the getItem method from the EWS api, and currently the only way i can get the itemId is by calling the saveAsync method from the OfficeJs library. This method returns the itemId if the meeting is created, but creates a new meeting if this is a new meeting window. So i want to call this method only when the meeting is in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Currently this feature, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of use cases where this is relevant:

I believe the purpose of many add-ins is to augment the item (e.g. appointment/meeting or email), the user is currently reading or composing. This is usually done in a 3rd party system by associating the meeting in Exchange with a "record" in a separate system. To find out if the current meeting is already associated with a "record" (and possibly display the contents of it), you need a way to identify the meeting obviously. If it's a new meeting, you know there isn't a "record", however if it's an existing meeting, you need to be able to identity it. Exposing itemId in compose mode would satisfy this need. And by the way, the feature is already [requested](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17923540-we-need-support-for-itemid-in-compose-mode-for-app) on User Voice!

I can only speculate as to why Microsoft haven't added the feature yet, but I think Office JS started out with support for emails. Compose-mode for emails is almost exclusively for authoring new (unsent) emails, hence they would never have an itemId.

This is not the case for appointments and meetings, however. They are frequently being edited after they have been created, as meetings are often rescheduled, augmented with a more detailed agenda, etc.

Unfortunately the workaround of using saveAsync to obtain the itemId has several drawbacks as you already alluded to: it's very intrusive as it will leave behind "ghost" meetings (as the user now can't regret saving an appointment/meeting) and it causes the sending of [spurious meeting update requests](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19134232-office-context-mailbox-item-saveasync-always-gener) to attendees, etc. And it doesn't work in Outlook for Mac! - one of the big selling points of this add-in technology compared to VSTO/COM-add-ins.

At my company we have attempted several times to port our existing VSTO add-in to Office JS, but everytime we stall on this exact issue, as the drawbacks are simply to many!

However, an approach - besides maybe using some crude heuristics - we have **thought** about, goes like this:

1) Via EWS (or MS Graph), augment every meeting(!) of every user(!) with a custom add-in property containing the itemId. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43140644/10752973 on how to set custom properties from the "outside".

2) When the add-in is opened, see if the custom property is present. If the custom property is there, it's an existing appointment/meeting (and you'll know its itemId). If it isn't there, it's a new appointment.

As I said, we haven't implemented it, but in theory it might work. But it's such a huge hassle (and will burden both the Exchange server and the application itself), for something so simple. We would effectively also need to monitor each mailbox in Exchange to detect newly creating appointment/meetings in order to augment them with the custom property, which is needlessly complex.

But I hope this answer might convince the [Outlook Add-ins Team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7823505/outlook-add-ins-team-msft) to reconsider adding support for obtaining itemId in compose-mode for appointments/meetings.