# HOWTO read Outlook custom property set with GRAPH

Tags: graph, office-js, custom-properties

I am using the Office.js CustomProperties interface to store application specific data. Using the Office.js library I can succesfully read the information back in different application sessions using Office.js.

A different API process needs to read this data using the MS Graph interface. I did read [Get custom property set in Outlook Add-In via Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130810/get-custom-property-set-in-outlook-add-in-via-microsoft-graph) but for me it does not work. I do get the message information but without any extended properties.

What is it that I am doing wrong? After putting a lot of time in this problem any help is so welcome...

Thanks in advance,

Wilco

Comment: Are you testing on the web client or the desktop client? The desktop client does not always immediately sync custom properties to the server, which could cause this issue.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT : I am using the online Outlook client. Using Office.js I can read the Custom properties without any problems. Using Graph from c# or the Graph Explorer does not show any extended properties.

Comment: Understood, does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130810/get-custom-property-set-in-outlook-add-in-via-microsoft-graph

Comment: Hello @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT. We explored all the examples and cases but cannot solve this problem. This the Graph Call we use **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages//{msgid}/?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%20{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}%20Name%20cecp-b5db42d1-a33c-4b2a-9eb8-96f406feeea9')** but it only returns the standard message properties. You can really make us happy people with some good advice!

Comment: any update on this ?