# Catch 22 situation with Office.js appointment integration

Tags: office365, office-js

There seems to be no way to get an appointment ID or any other unique reference without sending unwanted multiple emails to attendees. This problem seems to exist since 2017!

We need an ID of the appointment to relate information in our database to an appointment in Outlook. We have are forced to use SaveAsync in compose mode to get this ID. Even if the appointment is already saved! Using SaveAsync in Outlook online will immediately send unwanted emails to attendees. Furthermore you can only close the appointment dialog with your changes by sending even more emails to attendees. I cannot believe that it's acceptable for Microsoft that recipients of a meeting with an AddIn in Outlook online get at least 2 (identical) emails for every scheduled meeting.

An alternative way would be to store a unique id in extended properties as proposed in [Get custom property set in Outlook Add-In via Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130810/get-custom-property-set-in-outlook-add-in-via-microsoft-graph) . As we mentioned in [HOWTO read Outlook custom property set with GRAPH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073136/howto-read-outlook-custom-property-set-with-graph) we cannot get this to work.

Is there anything we are missing? Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.